# what are the features avaliable in Git-Lab over the Github?

Tags: github, gitlab

please let me know what are the different **between GitHub and Git-Lab**. I already use the GitHub as usual but recently I hear the term Git-Lab so I search and got over role information about **Git-Lab** although I want to clarify it through your answers

Comment: Approximately the same as the differences between Honda and Toyota, or between Pepsi and Coke: two different providers of a somewhat similar product with small differentiations here and there.

Answer (score 1):

Github and Gitlab are two completely seperate services that both provide web-based git repository management. The main difference I could spot was that Gitlab was heavily targeted to development teams.